# Post as app to facebook page

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

is it possible to post to page as the page itself (programmatically)?

I do have and python app and I want to be able to add posts to my page under the page account automaticaly.

Do I have to authenticate (get access token) as myself (I'm the page admin)? I also have an Facebook app, which has the page associated with itself, so maybe there is way how can I post to the page under the app credentials.

The thing is I don't want to have my personal account info in the python code. What is the common way to accoplish this?

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. First of all, you should get Page access token as described [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#pagetokens) - and it will be permanent one, so you won't need your personal account info hardcoded. After that, use that access token to post to the page's feed: `/##page_id##/feed`

note: if you get page access token using your short-lived user token, then the page token will be short-lived as well. To get permanent token for the page, as [Facebook documentation states](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#extending), you need to:

> To get a longer-lived page access token, exchange the User access
>   token for a long-lived one, as above, and then request the Page token.
>   The resulting page access token will not have any expiry time.

So the solution is:

1. get access token under my FB personal account (i.e. via GraphAPI Explorer)
2. exchange that token for long-lived via oauth/access_token?grant_type=fb_exchange_token call
3. Request page token via "me/accounts". The token is really never-expired and can    be validated via developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken

Comment: Thanks. But the access token to the page returned as response to "me/accounts" expires like in one hour.

Comment: updated my answer - basically you need to request page token using long-lived user token.

Comment: Great, but long-lived token remains about 60 days. Thus I do need to develop a give-me-token mechanism anyway. And this will be done under my FB account, which means login + password hardcoded to my account in my app. Right?

Comment: you are wrong - please read the link and/or the quote here - `The resulting page access token will not have any expiry time.`

Comment: Woho, great mate. I'm sorry I haven't read your answer carefully. So the solution is: 1. get access token under my FB personal account (i.e. via GraphAPI Explorer. 2. exchange that token for long-lived via "oauth/access_token?grant_type=fb_exchange_token......". 3. Request page token via "me/accounts". The token is really never-expired and can be validated via https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken

Comment: everything is correct - let me update my answer with the workflow :)